# It's posible to have google for work and office 365 accounts for the same domain: example.com?

Tags: dns, office365

I want to know if you can have for example:

myfirstmail@mydomain.com   - hosted with Google apps for work - Email

mysecondmail@mydomain.com  - hosted with office 365 -Email

I mean to point both mx records to the same domain, so you can have gmail and office 365 accounts for the same domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do a setup like that. You will need to setup a split delivery and the MX records should point to one of the services, you can choose which one.

More information about Split delivery on Google Apps here, https://support.google.com/a/answer/173534?hl=en.

More information about Split delivery setup on Office 365 here, https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/255242.

Hope it helps.